# How do I display fetched Data from MariaDB to a listview

Tags: database, flutter

So basically what i want to do is to display the data i get from my DB in a ListView, but I'm only able to show one attribute of my Object Device.

This my Class for device

```
class Devices {
  final int iD;
  final String location;
  final String type;
  Devices({required this.iD, required this.location, required this.type});
  factory Devices.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Devices(
        iD: json['id'] as int,
        location: json['Ort'] as String,
        type: json['Typ'] as String);
  }
}
```

The json i get from my PHP script looks like this

```
     {"id":1,"Ort":"Wohnzimmer","Typ":"Sensor"}
```

Code to show my Class

```
class DeviceList extends StatelessWidget {
  List<Devices> dList;
  DeviceList({super.key, required this.dList});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: dList.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        // return Text(dList[index].location,
        //     style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 40));
        return (ListTile(title: Text(dList[index].iD.toString())));
      },
    );
  }
}
```

I want to show all attributes of my Class at the same and not only the iD of it, but i have no clue how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in ListTile widget you can display your data like this

```
 ListView.builder(
      itemCount: dList.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Card(
          elevation: 4,
          child: ListTile(
            leading: CircleAvatar(
              child: Text("${dList[index].iD}"),
            ),
            title: Text(dList[index].type),
            subtitle: Text(dList[index].location),
          ),
        );
      },
    ),
```

which will look like this

[image]

there are a lot of other ways to display that data.

Comment: thank u for ur answer it helped a lot and also love the design !

Answer (score 1):

It depends on **how** you want to display the other attributes

if you want to use `ListTile` you probably want to make the use of the `leading` and `trailing`

```
return ListTile(
  leading: Text(
    dList[index].iD.toString(),
  ),
  title: Text(
    dList[index].location,
  ),
  trailing: Text(
    dList[index].type,
  ),
);
```

or use a `Row` inside the `title`, it's up to you

Comment: i eventually also came up with the idea  to use a row but that wasn't what i really wanted, but also thank u for ur solution it helped a lot !